# c Pointer to pointer, or passing list to functions

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to c programming. Could anyone please tell me what's wrong with 
the following program?

---

```
typedef struct Person_s
{
  int age;
  char name[40];
} Person_t;


int process_list(int *countReturned, Person_t **p_list)
{

  Person_t *rowPtr=0;
  //the actual program will fethc data from DB

  int count =1;

 if(!((*p_list) = (Person_t *) malloc(sizeof(Person_t))))
 {
    return -1;
 }

 rowPtr = *p_list;

 rowPtr[count-1].age =19;
 strcpy(rowPtr[count-1].name,"Prince Dastan");
 *countReturned = count;

  return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        Person_t *tmpPerson=0;
        Person_t **p_list=0;
        int *count=0;
        int i;

        process_list(count,p_list);

        tmpPerson = *p_list;

        for(i=0; i< *count; i++)
        {
           printf("Name: %s , age: %d\n",tmpPerson->name,tmpPerson->age);
           tmpPerson++;
        }

        //free(tmpPerson);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a code-review or is there a specific error ? If so, what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're setting the pointers to point to NULL (0), then dereferencing them. You are not allowed to dereference NULL. Want you want is more like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        Person_t tmpPerson;
        Person_t *p_list=0;
        int count;
        int i;

        process_list(&count, &p_list);

        tmpPerson = *p_list;
        // and so on...
```

The `&` is the "address-of" operator, which returns a pointer to the variable's address. So this passes a pointer to `count` and `p_list`, which your function then uses to set those variables, which appears to be what you want to do.

Comment: I need to retrieve a list with count from the process_list() function. "Person_t *p_list=0;" will this return a list?

Comment: @user361808: It returns a pointer to an array of `Pointer_t` (where the array may in fact just be a single Pointer_t, as in your test code).

Answer (score 1):

You should have in main:

```
Person_t *p_list=0;
...
process_list(count, &p_list);
```

The code as written passes in 0 to process_list, and then you have:

```
*0 = (Person_t *)malloc(...);
```

This causes 0 to be dereferenced, and your code will crash.

Comment: Passing `count` with `count` declared as `int *count = 0` will still dereference NULL and crash.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `p_list` as you enter the function is 0.  If you dereference 0 you get a Bus Error.

```
if(!((*p_list) = (Person_t *) malloc(sizeof(Person_t))))
```

(90% of C problems are caused by dereferencing a null pointer, just like 90% of Java problems are caused by a misconfigured *classpath*.  :-)